# Spring MVC - При обращении к RestController, возникает org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException

Tags: json, spring, mvc

Пишу web-приложение на Spring MVC (5.2.8).
Создал REST-контроллер, следующего вида:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("message")
public class MessageController {
    private List<Map<String, String>> messages = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>() {{
        add(new HashMap<String, String>() {{ put("id", "1"); put("text", "First message"); }});
        add(new HashMap<String, String>() {{ put("id", "2"); put("text", "Second message"); }});
        add(new HashMap<String, String>() {{ put("id", "3"); put("text", "Third message"); }});
    }};
    @GetMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Map<String, String>> list() {
        return messages;
    }
}
```

Конфигурацию web-приложения делаю при помощи "Java Config", файл WebConfig.java имеет следующий вид:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "ru.egar")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public WebConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");

        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
        return viewResolver;
    }


    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }

}
```

Приложение успешно запускается на Tomcat. В браузере при обращении по адресу:
http://localhost:8080/message
получаю ошибку вида:

[image: Http status 500]

Подскажите, какой конфигурации не хватает для корректного отображения JSON-ответа?

Answer (score 2):

После "многочасового гуглежа" нашёл ответ на свой вопрос. Решение следующее:

1. Добавляем зависимость (в случае Maven - в pom.xml):

   com.fasterxml.jackson.core
          jackson-databind
          2.11.2
2. В файле Spring-конфигурации (в моём случае WebConfig.java) дополнительно описываем четыре метода:

1. @Bean mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()
2. @Override void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer)
3. @Bean ObjectMapper objectMapper()
4. @Override void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)

По итогу мой файл WebConfig.java выглядит следующим образом:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "ru.egar")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public WebConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");

        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
        return viewResolver;
    }


    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }


    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter =
                new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());
        return mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        objMapper.setSerializationInclusion(
                JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        objMapper.setDateFormat(df);
        return objMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }
}
```